# how to combine selected worksheets in same workbook using python

Tags: python, excel

Need a suggestion

my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import openpyxl
df = pd.read_excel('workbook.xlsx', sheet_name='Sheet1')  
df_writer = pd.ExcelWriter('workbook.xlsx', engine='openpyxl')
excel = openpyxl.load_workbook('workbook.xlsx')
df_writer.book = excel


for string in ['A','B','C','D','E','F']:
    df[df['column 1'].str.contains(string)].to_excel(df_writer,sheet_name=string)

writer.save()
writer.close()
```

Now here I have separated my data which contains certain string and saved in different sheets in same workbook.

Each sheet named as 'A','B','C','D','E','F'
I need to combine the sheets named  'A' and 'B' together to use for further analysis in same workbook with different name say "Combined"
both sheet 'A' and 'B' has same number of columns and headers.

any suggestion would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use string contain method with `A|B` to find either of `A` or `B` values in column and include them, save it to new sheet as:

```
import pandas as pd
import openpyxl
df = pd.read_excel('workbook.xlsx', sheet_name='Sheet1')  
df_writer = pd.ExcelWriter('workbook.xlsx', engine='openpyxl')
excel = openpyxl.load_workbook('workbook.xlsx')
df_writer.book = excel


for string in ['A','B','C','D','E','F']:
    df[df['column 1'].str.contains(string)].to_excel(df_writer,sheet_name=string)

df[df['column 1'].str.contains('A|B')].to_excel(df_writer,sheet_name='Combined')
#Now your excel contains all 'A','B','C','D','E','F' and 'Combined' sheet.

writer.save()
writer.close()
```

Comment: Hi, I have `workbook=file.xlsx.``In that I have several sheets named `Data1,Data2,Data3,Data4`. Can you please tell me how can I combine using these name of the sheet. for example combining `Data1 & Data2` and saving it in new sheet `Combined_Data1`. Help please.

Comment: @user10309160 read the data into different dataframes then use `pd.concat` function to join all of them and then save the combined dataframe to your desired sheet.

Comment: @user10309160 Glad to help!

Comment: Hi can you solve this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52494617/python-splitting-dataframe