# Python-Splitting dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

My goal is to group the dataframe based on the `column['quantity']` in the below dataframes

my dataframe :

```
df
  ordercode             quantity
PMC21-AA1U1FBWBJA           1
PMP23-GR1M1FB3CJ            1
PMC11-AA1U1FJWWJA           1
PMC11-AA1U1FBWWJA+I7        2
PMC11-AA1U1FJWWJA           3
PMC11-AA1L1FJWWJA           3

 df1:
  ordercode             quantity
PMC21-AA1U1FBWBJA           1
PMP23-GR1M1FB3CJ            1
PMC11-AA1U1FJWWJA           1
PMC11-AA1U1FBWWJA+I7        2

df2
  ordercode             quantity
```

My coding:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.concatenate(df.apply(lambda x: [x[0]] * x[1], 1).as_matrix()), 
          columns=['ordercode'])
df['quantity'] = 1
df['group'] = sorted(list(range(0, len(df) // 3, 1)) * 4)[0:len(df)]
df = df.groupby(['group', 'ordercode']).sum()
print(df)
```

With the above coding I got my result in `df` as below.

```
  Group    ordercode                quantity
    0       PMC21-AA1U1FBWBJA           1
            PMP23-GR1M1FB3CJ            1
             PMC11-AA1U1FJWWJA          1
            PMC11-AA1U1FBWWJA+I7        1
    1      PMC11-AA1U1FBWWJA+I7         1
            PMC11-AA1U1FJWWJA           3
    2      PMC11-AA1L1FJWWJA            3
```

In `group0 & group1`  the total values (1+1+1+1=4)(1+3=4)(i.e keeping the max vale of quantity as 4). In `group2` we can see that no values to add so the group is formed by the left over(here it is 3).in  `group0 & group1` we can see that `PMC11-AA1U1FBWWJA+I7`'s value splits.

No problem in it.

In `df1` & `df2` its showing value error.

in df1:

```
value error: length of values does not match length of index
 raise Value error('length of value does not match length of index')
```

in df2:

```
 value error:need at least one array to concatenate.
```

I could understand that my `df2` is empty and has no `index`. I used `pd.Series` but again the same error.

how to solve this problem?